# How to Use Global Variables Inside Header and Footer

Tags: functions, users, globals

I set [global variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) for some custom user data in my functions.php to use them in navigation inside header and footer.

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    # users wordpress id
    global $user_id_wp;
    $user_id_wp = get_current_user_id();
    # users meta page id
    global $user_id_meta;
    $user_id_meta = userMeta(get_current_user_id());
    # users uuid
    global $user_id_uuid;
    $user_id_uuid = get_field("user-uuid", $user_id_meta);
}
```

Those variables cannot be used inside `header.php` and `footer.php` where I need them. Cannot be used means `var_dump($user_id_meta)` results in `NULL`, while `userMeta($user_id_wp)` shows the correct values inside header or footer.

I have tried to set the lines above as function with `add_action( 'init', 'globalUserVar' );` but no positive results either. Please help me use my global user vars inside the header and footer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't simply call `get_current_user_id()` (as well as `userMeta()` and `get_field()`) in your header and footer templates?

Comment: Global variables are generally a bad idea. Rather than using them I'd suggest writing functions that return the values you want and using that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, that would have been my "workaround", but if you think it's the better solution, I prefer that for future needs.

Comment: Thanks, @SallyCJ. I really don't need the $user_id_wp, but those other two are needed independently of each other through the theme, not only in header and footer. That's simply easier for me.

Comment: @RobinAlexander What I was saying is, for example in `footer.php`, `sidebar.php` or a template *part*, why not just call `userMeta(get_current_user_id())` or (by passing a specific user ID - `userMeta( 123 )`) right in that template file? And same goes with `get_field()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `functions.php` you can create a constant with the user id, like this.

```php
// if somehow this constant exists this will prevent a php error
if (!defined('CURRENT_USER_ID')) {
    // if user is not logged it this constant will contain 0
    define('CURRENT_USER_ID', get_current_user_id());
}
```

Now you have a constant variable available anywhere in your theme.

To access it you can simply call it, for example

```php
echo CURRENT_USER_ID;
```

Comment: Never thought of constants! Great solution. Thank you very much for helping so fast!